# Extend the vector of results during loop

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I would like to create a vector containing my results from a loop. The results are vectors themselves, and they do not have the same length.

Right now I have the code

```
totalres <- NULL
loop begins
totalres <- c(totalres,loopres)
loop ends
```

but I've been told this is a very slow code. As I have many iterations and a big data.table I would like to know, whether there is a faster way of doing it?

Comment: Please show a reproducible example with expected output

Comment: there are many ways to optimize `data.table` operations, so code & data would help. for straight `data.frame`, `sapply` will _probably_ be more efficient than a `for` loop.

Comment: Read Circle 2 of the "R Inferno" http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: @hrbrmstr and `vapply` will be _surely_ more efficient than `sapply` (which I think should rarely, if ever, be used).

Comment: @nicola aye. most of my work is interactive, so I rely heavily on the reduced typing of `sapply`. Totally agree that in functions and production (i.e. batch) pipelines `vapply` is far superior.

Answer (score 0):

Three possibilities with loops:

If you have a `for` loop, you know how big your result will be. Allocate a vector of the needed length, e.g., `totalres <- numeric(n)`, and fill it. (Or use a function from the `apply` family. These do this for you.)

If you don't know how big the result will be, but know an upper size limit, overallocate to this maximum size and reduce the length after the loop.

If you can't estimate such an upper limit, allocate to a reasonable size and check inside the loop if the size is still sufficient. If the vector is full, grow, but not only by one element but by a bunch of elements.

Of course, it would be better to avoid loops at the R level and use a vectorized solution.